# Can udev be 'restarted' without a reboot?

Tags: redhat, vmware-vsphere, udev

For the general case let's say that the virtual adapter for eth0 has been removed and replaced with another one. Either due to cloning or, more recently, a rash of MAC address conflicts. [Yes, a *rash* of them.]

Usually I simply `rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules` and check that nothing in /etc/sysconfig/network* contains a reference to a MAC address and *reboot*, but this is Linux and there must be a way to avoid rebooting.

Is there a command I can run to pick up the new NIC?

### edit

In addition to @dawud's answer below I ran into an issue on my test VM where it had already booted with the new device in place and had it named `eth1` in which case `udevadm` does not seem to 'release' the device. In this case I did the following:

1. Get the MAC address of the device from VSphere.
2. Create/edit `/etc/iftab` with the line `eth0 mac ##:##:##:##:##:##` substituting in the MAC address. `ifrename` does not seem to like it when this file does not exist/contain the name of the destination interface.
3. `ifrename -i eth1 -n eth0`
4. `service network restart` and eth0 started up normally.
5. [Optional] `rm /etc/iftab` so there's one less place for a MAC to live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `udevadm trigger`

You still need to remove the persistent rules and restart the network service.

Comment: Something like `service network stop && udevadm trigger --action=change && service network start`? I did a little reading on `udevadm` and `action=change` is supposed to be safer than the default `action=add`.

Comment: Provided you have already removed the persistent rules, yes, that should do. These [link](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2009-January/027260.html) may be of interest.

Comment: I was actually just reading that before you linked to it. :D

Answer (score 2):

For me, the below command sequence has worked as expected.

I have done modifications in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to change the `eth` number and to reload them without rebooting.

`/etc/init.d/networking stop`

`/etc/init.d/udev stop`

`udevadm control --reload-rules`

`/etc/init.d/udev start`

`/etc/init.d/networking start`

Following this, it successfully loaded without rebooting the machine.

Any suggestion or recommendations on this are welcome, I have discovered the above on my own by reading the MAN pages.